# switching domain to new project from old project

Tags: google-app-engine, dns, project

I'm updating our site with a new project and trying to change which project uses the domain (I'd also like the keep the old project online). I removed the custom domains on the old project (ProjectA) under "Settings/Custom domains," then added the domain to the new project (ProjectB), just in case I checked ProjectB's A, AAAA, and CNAME matched Google domains DNS; all looks correct.

The problem is after 48 hours; the domain is still pointing to ProjectA.

So I disabled ProjectA within "Setting/Application settings", checked the xxx.appspot.com address, and it was indeed disabled. However, when using the domain, it was still directing to ProjectA (yes, opening a disabled project! - this project isn't a static site).

I'm at a bit of a loss about setting my domain to work on ProjectB; any help would be excellent.

Comment: Did you clear your browser cache?  Try using another browser to make sure you aren't seeing browser-cached version

Comment: Yes I've tried that it's still showing ProjectA

Comment: Did you go thru the domain verification process for the new app?  You want to re-verify you own the domain when you tell it which app to point to.

Comment: You can only verify once then that domain is added to your domain list, also as I've pointed out the domain works as it continues to point to ProjectA, I'm looking to point it to ProjectB.

Answer (score 1):

Check the full region URL of your site; it's on the top left of the App-Engine dashboard.

Also, check the Projects shortened URL is set-up as expected; this needed adjustments. Now the Domain is reaching the correct location.